# Splitting a data frame by median

Tags: r

I want to separate my data set into two subsets, where the one half contains all values below the median and the other half contains values above the median.

Problem: my data set has multiple observations with the same value as the median. Therefore,

```
v <- c(1,2,3,3,3,3,3,4)
med <- median(v)
upper <- v[which(v >= med)]
lower <- v[which(v <= med)]
```

doesn't work because the values equal to the median will appear in both sets and be overrepresented.

My expected output is

```
lower: 1,2,3,3
upper: 3,3,3,4
```

How can I split my dataframe by the median in R?

Comment: ok i fixed the post to include a reproducible example.

Comment: Just use strict inequalities? `>` and `<`

Comment: You can basically either choose to exclude the median entirely by using strict inequalities, put the median in the upper or lower half, but not both, or split the rows equal to the median between the two `data.frames`. Depending on what you're trying to do, one option may make more sense than the other.

Comment: If I exclude the median values, I will bias the data. I don't understand how that would work. 

I could index the data after ordering it by my variable and then split the data by the median of the index. I assume there's a function that does that, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: How do you decide that two of those 3's should be in `lower` and three of them should be in `upper` ?

Comment: `split(v, rep(c(1, 2), each = length(v)/2))` should do it as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your requirement, we just need to split the sorted vector in half. However, we need to account for cases where we have an odd number of elements, and so we use `round(length(v))` to get the nearest integer element for odd length vectors:

```
v <- sort(v)
lower <- v[1:round(length(v)/2)] 
upper <- v[round((length(v)/2)+1):length(v)] 

lower
[1] 1 2 3 3
upper
[1] 3 3 3 4
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution is for data frames.

```
df <- df[order(df$var),] 
med <- median(df$var) 
lower <- df[1:round(nrow(df)/2),] 
upper <- df[round((nrow(df)/2)+1):nrow(df),]
```

Mako212 shows the method works. See his/her post.